Understanding some concepts regarding metric spaces.
I already know the base definition and 4 axioms. The things I don't know are completeness, compactness, and connectivity.
Also, in the example:
$\gamma: [0, 1]\to D$, $\gamma(0) = z_1, \gamma(1) = z_2$ (where $D$ is metric space, and $z_1$ and $z_2$ are points),
"density metric in D" $\varphi(z)$ is mentioned,
$\varphi : D\to [0, +\infty)$,
$\varphi(\gamma) = \int_\gamma {\varphi(z)\left|dz \right|}$
also mentioned "geodesic line" $\varphi = \int_a^b{\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}dx}$
The limit value of strings in metric space seems intuitive. The terms completeness and compactness are familiar to me from other fields, but the density of metrics, the appearance of integrals and the geodesic line completely confuse me.
I couldn't find any material where these are concisely and well explained. Can anyone explain what are these? Course I am having this in is Real Analysis I, and although metric spaces are done more in detail on Real Analysis II, I guess this should just be an introductory level but it still doesn't seem trivial to me except the basic definition of a metric and metric space.

I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for a short tutuorial on metric spaces. You have been on this site long enough to know that you should ask one particular question at a time and show your work on it.

@EthanBolker I can't find any tutorials on those specifics. This was an introductory class on metric spaces and after defining a metric space and axioms, it went straight to this so I am completely confused. What I am asking in particular is what is geodesic line and it's relation to metric space, what is density metric etc. I never got explanations for these hence my question is a bit more broad than it should be.

an introductory class on metric spaces --- What is your textbook? What are the suggested reading/references? What references has your teacher mentioned during lectures? I ask because this type of problem is NOT something dealt with in an introductory course on metric spaces (which you claim to be taking) -- examples: Shirali/Vasudeva AND Sutherland AND O'Searcoid AND Magnus AND Bryant.

To continue my previous comment, this looks like an exercise one might find in a metric spaces chapter in a complex analysis text or differential geometry text, or perhaps in lectures specifically intended for complex analysis or diff. geometry applications. Introductory metric space courses tend to be like introductory general topology courses in that very little from previous mathematics courses is required, at least at the beginning -- high mathematical maturity, but not something like integration with respect to $|dz|,$ which is not a metric space notion anyway as far as I'm aware.

@DaveL.Renfro I will be honest with you, our university professors are not always sane... This course is called Real Analysis 1 and is held in both semesters of first year mathematics faculty. Topics it covers are sets, sequences, limits, functions, differentiation, integration and ends with series. Real Analysis 2 is course on 2nd year that deals with metric spaces, multi-variable calculus etc. Not sure if these were just examples but on this same page in my notebook is the definition of metric along with 4 axioms that I consider introductory. I also had Logic and Linear Algebra courses etc.

In that same lecture, open/closed balls are also mentioned. euclidean metric $\mathbb{R}^n$, open/closed sets, Holder and Minkowski inequalities, I think this was some sort of general introduction to Analysis (after axioms for addition/multiplication but before sequences and limits). It really looks out of place I know and that's why I made this post being completely confused. As for textbooks, we don't have officials only recommended ones but it all varies on what professor is teaching (each one does it differently, some don't go through metrics but mine did).

By the way, here's first page of that lecture: https://prnt.sc/qgAwyqNXOMlJ
It really looks like everything is out of place

Possibly useful is p. 6 and nearby pages of NOTES FOR MATH 4510, FALL 2010 (internet archived version, in case this comment survives longer than the web page I'm citing) by Domingo Toledo.

Not being able to read the language of your notes, I cannot be sure, but the part you highlight seems to be describing one way to define a metric on a space $D$, provided $D$ already has a concept of differentiation and integration defined on it (presumably $D$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ which is nice enough to still allow calculus). The "metric density" is just some arbitrary positive function on $D$ used to define the metric. the formula you label "geodesian line" is just the formula for arclength of a plane (2D) curve described by the equation $y = f(x)$.

@Paul Sinclair: I was thinking essentially the same thing, that a lot more was said in class than was written in the notes. Probably the notes represent only what was written on the blackboard (or whiteboard, or whatever people use now).

For your questions about completeness, connectedness, and compactness, you need to familiarize yourself with various examples. The quintessential examples of metric spaces are subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ with Euclidean distance as the metric. These will give you an significant understanding of what metric spaces are. There are other metric spaces with behaviors that are not represented by subsets of $\Bbb R^n$, but these spaces are a good starting point for exploration.
A metric space is complete if it has no "holes" in it. That is, there is no place where a point should be, but there is no point there. What determines if a point should be is Cauchy sequences. In $\Bbb R^n$, a sequence converges if and only if it is Cauchy. But if you are looking at subsets, the limit of the convergent sequence might not be included in the subset, even when the entire sequence is.

Subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ are complete if and only if they are closed. That is, if they contain all their boundary points. $\Bbb R^n$ itself is complete. But $D = \Bbb R^n \setminus \{0\} = \{x\in \Bbb R^n: x \ne 0\}$ is not complete. Any sequence that converges to $0$ and doesn't have $0$ as one of its elements is also a Cauchy sequence in $D$, but does not converge there. Any subset of $\Bbb R^n$ which is not closed is also an example.

A space is connected if it is all in one piece. For an initial understanding, you can look at a somewhat stronger condition called "path-connected". A space is path-connected if for any two points $x,y$ in it, there is some continuous curve $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0) = x, \gamma(1) = y$. A space that is path-connected is also connected. The opposite is not true - there are connected spaces that are not path-connected, but these are esoteric, not something one commonly encounters. So path-connectedness captures most of what connectedness is, and is a good starting point for understanding the concept.

An open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is connected if you can "graph" it as a single "blob". But if graphing it requires two or more blobs, it will be disconnected. In $\Bbb R$, intervals are examples of connected sets (in fact, they are exactly the connected subsets of $\Bbb R$, if you consider $[a,a]$ to be an interval). Disconnected sets include unions of two or more separated sets - sets whose closures do not intersect. But $\Bbb Q$ is an example of a disconnected set that is not such a union. Finally, the Topologist's sine curve is a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ which is connected, but not path-connected, illustrating why path-connectedness is stronger than connectedness itself.
An example of the usefulness of connectedness: Suppose that $f : D \to \Bbb R$ is a function with $D$ an open set in $\Bbb R$, and $f$ is differentiable everywhere. If $f' = 0$ everywhere, then we can only say $f$ is constant if $D$ is connected. If $D$ is not connected, all we can claim is that $f$ is "locally constant". For each point $x \in D$, there is some open set about $x$ on which $f$ is constant. But we cannot declare it constant everywhere. For example, $D= (0,1)\cup(1,2)$ and $f(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor$ has $0$ derivative everywhere in $D$, but takes on two values.

Finally, subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ are compact if and only if they are closed and bounded (note that this is a special property of $\Bbb R^n$ with the Euclidean metric - it is not true in general). For metric spaces, compactness is equivalent to "sequential compactness", which is the condition that any sequence in the space will have a convergent subsequence. Any bounded sequence in $\Bbb R^n$ will have convergent subsequences. But an unbounded sequence may not have them.  Note that if a space is compact, then it is also complete. Completeness for subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ only requires the set to be closed. Compactness requires it to also be bounded.

Any closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is an example of a compact space. On the other hand, the natural numbers are themselves a sequence in $\Bbb R$ without any convergent subsequence, showing that $\Bbb R$ is not compact. Similarly, $(0,1)$ is not compact because $\frac 1k$ is a sequence in it with no convergent subsequence.
As an example of the usefulness of compactness, sometime in this course you are likely to learn about "uniform continuity", where you take the definition of continuity at a point $x$, and require for a given $\epsilon$, the same $\delta$ work for every $x$ in the domain $D$ of the function. For any continuous function $f$ on $D$, each point $x$ has a neighborhood where the same $\delta$ will work for every point in that neighborhood. If $D$ is compact, then the entire set $D$ is covered by a finite number of those neighborhoods. The smallest $\delta$ for neighborhoods in that finite cover will work everywhere. Thus a continuous function on a compact set is automatically uniformly continuous. ($f(x) = \frac 1x$                                   defined on $(0,1)$ is an example of a function that is not uniformly continuous.)

As I said in the comments, the "metric density" was clearly a means of defining metrics in special cases, not a discussion about metric spaces in general. and your "geodesian line" formula is actually just the arc-length formula for a plane curve defined by $y = f(x)$. "Geodesics" are the equivalent to a line on a surface. If the surface is a plane, then the geodesics are the lines of the plane. For other surfaces, the geodesics will be curves in the surface that connect any two points on it with minimal length. Apparently this came up in the class discussion, but your note-taking was completely inadequate here. Sorry, but take better notes in the future.

Hmm so regarding compactness, if I exclude Euclidean examples, would regular definition still work for a generic metric space as well? (If every open cover of a set has a finite subcover of that set.) I am still trying to kinda understand what is a metric space, set family etc. Would a metric space just be a set that includes a function that is measuring distance between 2 of its elements?

Yes, that is the accepted definition of compactness. It applies not just to all metric spaces, but to all topological spaces (which are defined by specifying what subsets of the space are open - metrics are just one way of doing so). And yes, a metric space is a set endowed with a specified metric function (i.e., a function that satisfies the three axioms).
